# Java .contains not actually searching my arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Edit: re-writing the whole question.

```
public static int search(ArrayList addressBook)//handles all search functionality
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String searchModifier;//declaring variables
        int noEntry = -1;

        System.out.print("\n\nPlease enter value to search for: ");//empowering the user
        searchModifier = input.next();//gathering searchModifier
                
        System.out.print (addressBook);
                
        if(addressBook.contains(searchModifier))//if their searchModifier is found
            return addressBook.indexOf(searchModifier);//return that index value
        else
            return noEntry;
    }
```

Above is the function I'm having issues with. I call this from another file. When I insert System.out.print(addressBook) into the system before the "if" statement, I get the following:

[image: arrayList output]

Clearly, it's in there. Why isn't it showing up?

Comment: this is impossible. post your addressBook object and searchModifier. may be is something related with equals and hash code.

Comment: If your addressBook contains only `Strings` and your `searchModifier` is itself a String, then you are incorrect about your assumption.

Comment: to disprove your hypothesis, you can just put addressBook.add(searchModifier) at the beginning

Comment: We don't know what any of the types involved are, with no evidence of the value being present. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would make it *much* easier to help you.

Comment: addressBook is just an arraylist of strings. searchModifier is just a string as well.

Comment: Please update your question and show us what `searchModifier` is and what `addressBook` contains. And please, don't write what it _should_ contains, just call `System.out.println(addressBook);` and post the result.

Comment: then your searchModifier is not present in list, it's simple

Comment: check if you don't have spaces mismatch in Strings in List and your searchModifier. try using trim()

Comment: also check if the case matches

Comment: oh my god, this list is full of objects, and none of them is a string!

Comment: Your list contains elements like *"First Name: a"* or *"Zip Code: a"* (#). These are _completely_ different strings than just *"a"*. No wonder it couldn't find `searchModifier`. (#) Or or contains something completely different and the output is the result of overriden `toString()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "searchModifier"? It has to be same String which should be present in your ArrayList and `contains` is **case sensitive search**.
If you are trying to search just a part of string then  `ArrayList.contains()` is not meant for it.

**EDIT**
You can do something like below but you have to loop, that's the only catch.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            if(arrayList.get(i) != null && arrayList.get(i).toLowerCase().contains("your_match_String".toLowerCase())){
                //Match found...
            }
        }
```

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom Indeed it turned out to be, as I expected.

Comment: Yes, so I see. I have deleted my previous comment.

Comment: Whoever is down-voting: the OP is adding pertinent information as we go along, which is causing everyone to reevaluate their answers. Don't assume you know what's going on if you don't.

Comment: Is there something similar to .contains that would work even if I've only got part of the string?

Comment: @DanCallahan: you could try something like `if (item.toLowerCase().trim().indexOf(searchModifier.toLowerCase().trim()) != -1)...`

Comment: No such method in ArrayList API but for such a narrow search you can loop through your list and then use same method on String, which supports your requirement. `"asds5d5dfdf".contains("5d5")` will give `true`.

Comment: @DanCallahan See my edit to original, you can do something like that.

Comment: @AlvinThompson *"Don't assume you know what's going on if you don't."* I'm not the downvoter, but to be honest, this sentence also matches your and hagrwals answer. You both answered a very unclear question with just some assumptions. It is nice that you tried to help OP, but this question should be flagged as "unclear what you're asking" and closed until OP provided enough information about his problem till it can be answered properly.

Comment: @Tom: Often the asker of a question doesn't know enough about what's going on to provide the relevant details until prompted. If there weren't confusion, the poster wouldn't be asking the question. Are you saying that we should not try to help these people because they don't have a strong enough understanding to provide the needed details on the first try?

Comment: @AlvinThompson You still can write a comment to request clarification.

Comment: @Tom: some of us have been software engineers for a long time and have developed an intuitive sense for what a likely issue is. It can often save a great deal of time to "cut to the chase" and guess at the likely problem. Of course, this has to be balanced against any wasted time for wrong guesses, but I don't think anyone I've seen here is anywhere close to that being an issue. It's often much faster to take 10 quick guesses of likely causes then to systematically produce one theory which might explain the issue. I guess we have a difference of opinion on what the bar should be for answers.

Comment: @AlvinThompson I guess this is related to the [fastest gun in the west problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `contains` there because it searches for an exact, case-sensitive match. Instead, manually iterate through the entries and return the index if an element matches your criteria (substring, case-insensitive).

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList.contains(Object) does indeed search the entire ArrayList to see if it contains a value that equals() the provided argument. In your case, it is looking to see if there is a value in addressBook such that value.equals(searchModifier).

Your names are confusing, though. addressBook is an `ArrayList<T>` where T is the same type as searchModifier (or a supertype thereof)? Who would expect that an address book would contain search modifiers?

Now that you've modified your question, it's clear that you don't understand. You have some class, we'll call it X, with String fields (First, Last, etc.). Your addressBook variable is of type `ArrayList<X>` (or something similar, like maybe `ArrayList<Object>`). Your problem is that searchModifier isn't an X, it's a String. You're trying to find an X in addressBook that has searchModifier as a field value. That's not the same as finding searchModifier in addressBook.

You can't use the contains() method to get the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your list contains Address objects, not strings.

Obviously, you can't find a string in a list of adresses.

Comment: My original answer would have been correct if that were the case. Where do you see mention of an `Address` object?

Comment: @AlvinThompson It's just intuition  :)

Comment: Concise, and answers the question completely. The OP asked why, not how can I fix it.